# Issue when using Date strings as parameter of CRUD query

Tags: reactjs, typescript, crud

In our react (typescript) project I have a call to a query to retrieve data within a date interval

```
const reqData = {
  start: start.toISOString(),
  end: end.toISOString(),
};
const { isLoading, isError, error, data: sessions } =  
useGetAllSessionsBetweenDatesQuery(reqData);
```

My issue is that this doesn't work

```
const today: Date = new Date();
const end: Date = new Date(today);//or const end: Date = new Date(today.getTime());
const start: Date = new Date(end.getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30);
```

But this work

```
const today: Date = new Date();
const end: Date = new Date(
    today.getFullYear(),
    today.getMonth(),
    today.getDate(),
    today.getUTCHours(),
    today.getUTCMinutes(),
    today.getUTCSeconds(),
  );

const start: Date = new Date(end.getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30);
```

What I mean by it does not work is that `isLoading` never goes to false and `sessions` stays undefined